# Directionality of mesh parts

Tags: vector, 3d, mesh, direction, meshlab

I created my meshes from 3D-scan data (.ply). Each mesh represent the void structure in an object so is composed of many disconnected components. I am interested to quantify the directionality of the voids. Is there any way to get the angle for the direction of the longest axis for each element of my mesh? I am using MeshLab but if anybody knows another software that could work, I am open to suggestions. Thanks!
Mathieu